# Creating custom autofill with numerical values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, auto-form-fill

Each day of the year has a value which I would like to consolidate by day of the week, i.e. all 52 Mondays consecutively, all 52 Tuesdays consecutively etc.  They are recorded chronologically on Sheet 1, and when organizing them by weekday on the consecutive sheet, the one that I made for 2013 (and can't remember for the life of me how I got it to do this automatically) looks like:

```
A     B
Mon   =Sheet1!O7
Mon   =Sheet1!O14
Mon   =Sheet11O21

...

Tue   =Sheet!O8
Tue   =Sheet!O15
Tue   =Sheet!O22
```

**My question is how do I autofill with a specific pattern?**  The weekdays for 2014 are shifted backwards by one, so the first Monday of the year would let's say be O6 now instead of O7 and unless I remember how to copy a formula but minus one from the cell reference then the formulas are off by a day.  If I try selecting `=Sheet!O6` and `=Sheet!O13` and dragging to autofill, instead of adding seven and making the next cells `=Sheet!O20` and `=Sheet!O27`, it makes them `=Sheet!O8` and `=Sheet!O15`, so like:

```
=Sheet!O6
=Sheet!O13
=Sheet!O8
=Sheet!O15
=Sheet!O10
=Sheet!O17
```

instead of:

```
=Sheet!O6
=Sheet!O13
=Sheet!O20
=Sheet!O27
=Sheet!O34
=Sheet!O41
```

How do I get the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `indirect` like:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet2!O"&ROW()*7-1)`

The **7** is your increment, and the **-1** is your initial offset (start at 6 on this). The **O** of course is the column number. Then you can drag this down.

You could also use an `index` to do the same type of thing.

Comment: Thank you - is that the only way it could have been done?  I'm trying to remember how I did it the first time, all the cells simply referred to the other sheet's cell and didn't use functions.

Comment: Maybe you did it manually or maybe you used a function and then converted the function to the *relative value* somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I know I didn't do it manually so special pasting is likely what I did.